# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ while using MVT.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, solution-verification

Following my last question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143348/question-about-a-sequence-a-n1-2a-n-1), I want to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ while using MVT.

Here is the complete question (I am trying to solve #3):

Let $0<t<1$ and define a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by:

$$a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}-1 ~~~ , ~~~ a_1=t$$

1. Prove that $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is decreasing. - DONE
2. Prove that $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}-1$ is convergent and compute its limit. - DONE, $L=0$
3. Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ while using MVT

Define $f(x)=\frac{2^x-1}{x}$ for every $x \in (0,1]$.

Working with the interval $[x,1]$, we get that there exists a $x<c<1$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\frac{2^x-x-1}{x^2-x}>0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing on that interval.

Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\ln2$, so $\ln2 \le f(x) \le 1$.

Here is where I need help:

Apply $x=a_n$ we get $\ln2 \le f(a_n) \le 1$, and than we need to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{a_n}-1}{a_n}$, which I think will eventaully be $\ln2$ because $n \to \infty$ while $a_n \to 0^+$, but I don't know how to calculate it properly.

Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is $(a_n)$???

Comment: @MartinR Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a_{n+1} = g(a_n)$ with $g(x) = 2^x - 1$. Then
$$
 \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{g(a_n)-g(0)}{a_n - 0} 
$$
It [has already been shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4143348) that $(a_n)$ converges to zero. It follows that
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{g(a_n)-g(0)}{a_n - 0} 
= \lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x - 0}= g'(0) = \ln 2.
$$
simply from the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you Martin, can you please explain why you can work in the interval $[0,a_n]$, because $g$ is not continuous at $0$, so MVT can't be done in this interval.

Comment: @Math4Me: $g(x) = e^x-1$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere. Btw, the MVT is not needed, this is simply the *definition* of the derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh right, I thought the function is different. Great, I will try it myself now - thanks!

Comment: Can you explain me how $n \to \infty$ became $x \to 0$ and not $x \to \infty$ as well?

Comment: @Math4Me: Because $a_n \to 0$ for $n \to\infty$.

Comment: Cool, thank you!